# Resource Group Name and Tenant ID in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

[image: Custom connecter screen shot]

I am new to using Azure logic app, and one thing that really bothers is that everything I create a custom logic app, I will have to enter the Resource Group Name and Resource Name in the UI to log my messages and exceptions.
Is there a way to automate or pre-populate this information?

Comment: Sorry, where exactly do you see this?  In the Portal?

Comment: Where do you mean "in the UI"? Could you add more detail to your question, and possibly a screenshot?

Comment: So, we created custom connectors for our customers, one example is a connector that parses HL7 message, and in order to log message and exceptions the current connector's design request user to input Resource Group Name and Resource Name while setting up the connector.Is there a way I could have the connector automatically detect user's subscription for those details. Added screen shot to the original question